# Powerpoint: How to automate sequential numbers across text boxes

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Background:

- There are two slides
- each slide has a set of 3 text boxes: each containing a number
- the numbers are to be sequential and not duplicative

Slide 1:  1,2,3
Slide 2:  4,5,6

The goal is to automate updating the number if a 4th or a 5th text box is added to slide 1:

Slide 1:  1,2,3,4,5
Slide 2:  6,7,8

Questions

- Does this capability have a name?
- If not, how to implement said capability?

This screenshot shows a set of manually sequenced numbered text boxes: it would be nice if they would automatically update, when a new number text box is inserted.

[image]

Comment: Maybe use a numbered list?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad  I tried a number list, but was unable to figure out how to move the next line item to the next text box.  Any ideas?

Comment: Link the boxes?

Comment: How is this done?  Can you provide a link to an example?